# How to manage storage between /dev/root and /dev/sda1

Tags: debian

I'm currently renting a dedicated server with 2TB of storage and I'm a beginner in server management.

I'm using it to host websites. All the websites sources are on the /var/www/html directory.

When checking how much space left I have, I get this :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   20G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G   19M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       487M   23M  435M   5% /boot
/dev/sda4       1.8T   31G  1.7T   2% /home
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

I have a lot of free space on /dev/sda4, but /dev/root is full, and when trying to transfer files by FTP to my server, I get errors saying that the disk space is full. How can I store my files on the /dev/sda4 disk ? Or how could I extend my /dev/root disk ?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

First some questions:

Q1. What is taking up all the disk space in the root (`/dev/root`) partition?
 To find this out, run the `du` command in a few places such as:

- `sudo du -sch /var/www/html`
- `sudo du -sch /var/*`
- `sudo du -sch /usr/*`
- You may want to run `du` on all the top-level directories underneath `/`, such as `/bin /etc /lib /usr /var` as well as other directories, with the intent of learning what is using the disk space in the root partition.

Q2. What is the layout of the disk: run `lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

If your problem is that the /var/www/html directory is filling up the root partition, then the simplest way around this is to move it to another partition, such as /home.

Solution: Move all the files and directories from `/var/www/html/` into `/home/web` (You will need to probably create `/home/web`.) And then symlink the object `/var/www/html` to the new `/home/web` directory.

```
mkdir -p /home/web
mv -v /var/www/html/* /home/web
cd /var/www
rmdir -i html/
ln -s /home/web html
```

Your Web server will not care that /var/www/html is now a symlink.

Notes: Before doing all this, you should 1) turn off your Web server (apache/nginx/etc) and 2) backup your data just in case.

Now your Webpages are being stored in the /home partition, which is much larger.

Alternatively, if you wish to not use the symlink above you can change your Web server configuration to serve files from `/home/web` instead of `/var/www/html`.

In the longer-term, I would consider re-imaging the server and changing your partition layout. Assuming you can backup your configuration files and data, I would consider re-imaging the server. If this computer is meant to server Web pages then there is really no reason to have a separate `/home` partition.

I would setup the 2 TB hard drive in the following way, note the numbers 1, 2, 3 are arbitrary:

- `/dev/sda1` - boot partition, 500 MB is fine,
- `/dev/sda2` - swap partition if desired, skip if server has sufficient RAM,
- `/dev/sda3` - one large root partition.

Then I would simply store all the files in the root partition, which could be in `/var/www/html`.